# Create Task from Python Mail

Tags: python, lotus-notes

is it possible to send a Task to a Lotus Notes user via python-mail (or any other SMTP client)?

I tried replicating the Notes fields and set it accordingly.

```
m['TaskType'] = '2'
m['Form'] = 'Task'
m['DueDate'] = '....'
```

and so on. But all I get is a (seems like) broken E-Mail which opens in the Task Form.
Also I get no Task in my To-Do List.

Here is a screen -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH0eW.png
Note that the [When] Form is missing.

Thanks

Comment: Please show all your code related to creating and sending the task, not just the parts you think are relevant. And also, fill in the exact format that you used for the DueDate. If it is not a hard-coded value, show us the exact value as it appears in a debugger. (BTW: have you tried a hard-coded value?)